# how to find distance and angle b/w each points in a point cloud and the Kinect sensor

Tags: ros, navigation, pcl, avoid-obstacle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Question : how to find distance and angle b/w each points in a point cloud and the Kinect sensor?

Details : Using the code provided in ROS PCL tutorial I subscribed to sensor message and generated a point cloud. Now I want to know how to find out the distance and angle b/w the point in the point cloud and the camera. There is a misconception that  point (x,y,z) in which z gives the distance from the camera to a point. If anybody got a solution, please post the answer in detail.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237717/how-to-find-distance-and-angle-b/w-each-points-in-a-point-cloud-and-the-kinect-sensor/) by [AbhijithNair](https://answers.ros.org/users/27243/abhijithnair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-06-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-30**:
If nobody answers your question, it's likely that either nobody knows, or that the people that do know haven't seen it. It's not like we're purposefully ignoring you.

In any case: could you please revert the edit to your question and post what you have now as an answer? Then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answer:

Hi, guys.

I figured a way to find out the point which is closer to the camera from the point cloud.
I shall share the code on the following link hoping that it might help you guys, also I
shall try to provide some insight into the code. Before reading my code I would recommend
you have a better understanding of coordinate frame conventions for the camera
( http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html ). I'm sharing the code in the below link.
https://github.com/abhijithanil/ROS_PCL_Kinect_distance_obstacle

Thanks

---

Originally posted by [AbhijithNair](https://answers.ros.org/users/27243/abhijithnair/) with karma: 41 on 2016-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2016-06-30**:
Thanks for sharing your code
but it is better to share it in github.

Stepstorun.txt:
You don't need 7 shells to execute your commands:

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2016-06-30**:
Shell:
$  roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
New shell:
$  cd ~/catkin_ws
$  catkin_make
$  source devel/setup.bash
$  rosrun test pub_kfc 
New shell:
$  source devel/setup.bash
$  rosrun test sub_kfc     
New shell:
$  rosrun rviz rviz
New shell:
$  roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_rob

**Comment by [AbhijithNair](https://answers.ros.org/users/27243/abhijithnair/) on 2016-06-30**:
Yeah.. i shall upload the whole project into github once i complete it. I know it is too awk to say i have no experience working with github. anyway thanks for your suggestion. i will consider that for my next upload. Hope my code helps and if its help, please flag it for others.  Thanks

**Comment by [GLV](https://answers.ros.org/users/37187/glv/) on 2019-04-16**:
@Mr.AbhijithNair could you please tell me how you convert Kinect data to point cloud. which packages did you use? could you please elaborate on how to find the distance from Kinect sensor in a stepwise.

thanks in advance